# ANTLR4 different precedence in two seemingly equivalent grammars

Tags: antlr4, operator-precedence

The following test grammars differ only in that the first alternative of the rule 'expr' is either specified inline or refers to another rule 'notExpression' with just the same definition. But this grammars produce different trees parsing this: '! a & b'. Why?

I really want the grammar to produce the first result (with NOT associated with identifier, not with AND expression) but still need to have 'expr' to reference 'notExpression' in my real grammar. What do I have to change?

```
grammar test;
s: expr ';' <EOF>;
expr:
    NOT expr
    | left=expr AND right=expr
    | identifier
    ;
identifier: LETTER (LETTER)*;
WS  :  ' '+ ->skip;
NOT: '!';
AND: '&';
LETTER: 'A'..'z';
```

[Tree one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U19sf.png)

```
grammar test;
s: expr ';' <EOF>;
expr:
    notExpression
    | left=expr AND right=expr
    | identifier
    ;
notExpression:  NOT expr;
identifier: LETTER (LETTER)*;
WS  :  ' '+ ->skip;
NOT: '!';
AND: '&';
LETTER: 'A'..'z';
```

[Tree two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i9ff.png)

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got an answer to the second part of my question, which still do not quite give me a satisfaction because using this approach in real elaborate grammar is going to be ugly. As to the first part (WHY) I still have no idea, so more answers are welcome.

Anyway, to fix precedence in presence of referenced rule the 'notExpression' rule can be modified as follows:

```
notExpression:  NOT (identifier|expr);
```

Which produces the tree different from both shown in original question, but at least the NOT does acquire higher precedence.
[Parse tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbsNk.png)